# Properties of functions over infinite sequences

Tags: category-theory

I'm looking for a characterization of functions over infinite sequences with the property that you can drop any number of elements without changing the result.

Example:
The function 'The function which maps to 1 if the sequence contains a finite number of zeros and to 2 otherwise'. The function value for every sequence is the same for every tail of the sequence.

I have a strong feeling that there is a category-theoretic characterization of such functions. I'm also interested in such functions over infinitely large trees (in which the result is the same for each sub-tree).

Comment: If you'd look instead at linear maps $T : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ then "throwing away any finite number of elements" becomes $T(\delta_i) = 0$ for every $i$ and $T((a_n)) = T((a_{n+1}))$

Answer (score 1):

These are just functions defined on the set of equivalence classes of sequences under the equivalence relation generated by left shift-that is, $(a_n)_n\sim (a_{n+1})_n$. You can describe this categorically as the coequalizer of the two endomorphisms of the set of sequences which send a sequence to itself, respectively, to its left shift.